# Use value from one query into the second one

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I use the value from one query into the second one. I tried with an alias "papa" but I read that the order of executions makes the alias not available to the second query.

What would be the appropriate way of achieving something like below ?

```
select id, name, parent_id as papa, (select name from people where id = papa)
from people;
```

Comment: That looks really strange. I guess you will get better answers when you show sample data and expected outcome as tables. Hard to believe this kind of subquery is correct at all.

Comment: You can't reference columns created/named in the same SELECT clause. Either have a derived table or cte, or use parent_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a self join for this:

```
select p.id, 
       p.name, 
       p.parent_id as papa_id,
       papa.name as papa_name
from people p
  left join people papa on p.parent_id = papa.id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/CuzE9V7D)

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "papa"
LINE 4:        papa.name as papa_name

Comment: @bluesony: there was a `,` missing. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Make the alias earlier

```
select id, name, papa, (select name from people where id = papa)
from (select id, name, parent_id as papa people);
```